# How to use Mocky API in reactjs with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone help me out how to call Mocky API in ReactJS by using Axios?

This is my CodeSandbox link : [MockyAPIReactJS](https://codesandbox.io/s/mockyapi-errh2?file=/ContextApi/index.js)

I have called the API in context API.
just want to console.log data other than that I will handle it.

```
userData=async()=>{
await axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ba8efb23100007200c2750c')
.then(res=>console.log(res.data))
.catch(err=>console.log("UserData Error",err))
}

componentDidMount(){
this.userData()
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code in the question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, which is running under the origin `https://codesandbox.io/` is trying to make an HTTP request to the origin `http://www.mocky.io/`. Most browsers block accessing non-secure URLs in the context of a secure URL, and that's what's happening to you.

Changing `http://www.mocky.io/` to `https://www.mocky.io/` seems to let the requests go through [as this fork shows](https://codesandbox.io/s/mockyapi-forked-tb4gn?file=/ContextApi/index.js).

Familiarize yourself with your browser's developer tools, particularly the network tab therein, since that will show you the reasons why requests are blocked.